# Nginx trouble loading css/images

Tags: configuration, nginx

I have configured NGINX and now it's working with php and html files. But it can't load images, *.js and *.css files. Here are my configuration files for NGINX.

This is my nginx.conf file

```
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;

        keepalive_timeout  65;

        #gzip  on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
     }
```

Here is the file default.conf that can be located at /etc/nginx/conf.d

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;
        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /home/username/www;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /home/username/www;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}


        ## Images and static content is treated different
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
          access_log        off;
          expires           max;
          root /home/username/www;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass   backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/username/www$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }

        upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Hopefully it writes something in `error.log` (BTW, I set it to `notice` even at my busy servers) Does it?

Comment: Okay, it says `(13: Permission denied)` when server tries to load some content.

Comment: Which means, well, permission is denied. Nginx cannot read the file, b/c it has no permission to do so. It says exactly what it says (surprise)

Comment: Thank you, I have already figured it out :)

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov I was not getting anything my logs. But that comment of yours saved me! Past two hours I have been trying to figure out why only images are loading and not js/css. Coz it had no permissions. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Can you please write a short answer - maybe with `chown` and `chmod` - and accept it? Otherwise it will show up in the search when you search for `nginx answers:0 score:1 duplicate:0 views:200`.